# why doesnt my render look like my preview render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light, hdri

[image]

I want the left one as my final render.

The left render is how i see it in preview with scene world turned off, but the right is what i get on my final render and when i enable scene world, i know its about HDR but i don't know how to fix it.

My guess is that the final render has scene world active by default. And i don't know if i should change that or i just messed up in my scene.

I have a portal and a spot lamp, disabled the volume scatter in the world because i think it affected the HDR, so i don't know what to do now.

im really new to blender.

as requested:
[image]

Comment: left right? can you check your question please? it's hard to understand your problem.

Comment: oh =P, my bad, i edited it and made it worse @sanbaldo

Comment: again, what's the problem? what it should be the right result?

Comment: i wanted the left render as my final render, but i keep getting the right one.

Comment: @sanbaldo sorry, brain stopped working for a sec.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the configuration of the world properties? (it's the tab with the "globe icon").

Comment: @sanbaldo here you go.